# How to solve the cfhtmltopdf encoding bug in coldfusion 11 update 8?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We have a system in coldfusion using cfhtmltopdf to generate reports in pdf.
The html of all reports are generated with the

```
  < meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

It was working well until we install the update 8 on it.
Now all the variables come from database has the acentuation bugged.

A "É" is showed like a "Ã%°"
A "Â" is showed like a "Ã,"

To fix the accentuation in the pdf just using encodeForHTML in each variable, and it's an impossible job, some reports have 200 variables from database.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bugged"? Can you post a *small* repro case that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: A "É" is showed like a "Ã%°"
A "Â" is showed like a "Ã,"

Comment: If it's a bug, *report it*.

Comment: Could you provide a vanilla HTML sample (w/DOCTYPE) that illustrates the problem?  Save the document as plain text to SO or Github/gist. (I'd like to test & compare results using CF9/10/11/2016 & WKHTMLTOPDF.)

Comment: CFDocument had a "pageencoding" parameter that can force a character set. CFHTMLTOPDF doesn't have that option. Is your HTML inline or are you using the "source" attribute?  If you generated & saved the HTML, did you use charset="iso-8859-1" when saving it?  Please provide more info regarding the HTML & CF code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cfprocessingdirective?

```
 <cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding = "iso-8859-1">

 </cfprocessingdirective>
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but didn't think it was a necessary hoop to jump through.  Is this required and does it work?  If so, it should be added to all existing documentation regarding both CFDocument & CFHTMLTOPDF.